# BizTalk Custom Pipeline Component - You have selected an invalid pipeline component assembly

Tags: c#, biztalk, unc, custom-pipeline-component

I am creating a class library. On successful build of that class library I had placed that DLL to the pipeline component folder of BizTalk Server and added that DLL to the GAC folder.

Now I am trying to refer that as custom pipeline component into another project where I am creating the custom pipeline. But when I try to add that DLL it throws an exception

> You have selected and invalid pipeline component assembly. Please check security settings for the assembly if you are loading it from an UNC path

I had already some of the solutions which are available related to this exception like

- First, check that your pipeline component class is public.
- Also, make sure any assemblies you reference from the custom pipeline component are in the GAC or Pipeline Components folder (if that’s where you drop your custom pipeline component assembly).
- Check for missing dependencies, they all have to be put on GAC or Pipeline Components folder

But still unable to resolve the issue.

Comment: Is your component a pipeline component or just a helper class? The question is not very clear on this, so could you please elaborate?

Comment: It is a helper class.But have properties related to that Pipeline component.It contains inheritance to the IPropertyBag and related stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, do not put custom Pipeline Components in the %Pipeline Components% folder.  Details on that here: [BizTalk Server: Deploying Custom Pipeline Components in BizTalk Server 2006 and Higher](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26404.biztalk-server-deploying-custom-pipeline-components-in-biztalk-server-2006-and-higher.aspx)

Next, you have to implement at least 2 but up to 5(?) Interfaces for a component to be recognized as a Pipeline Component.  The best way to ensure this is to use the excellent Pipeline Component Wizard available at CodePlex: [BizTalk Server Pipeline Component Wizard](http://btsplcw.codeplex.com/)

2013 R2 version here: http://btsplcw.codeplex.com/workitem/21354

Comment: Not putting it in the Pipeline folder and only GACing it is still a hotly debated topic ;-)   My recommendation, in a Dev environment in the folder only, in other environments GAC them as part of your automated deployment.

Comment: Thank you guys for the guidance but i want one more thing to be clarified is that is there anything related to that Resource file.Because what i observed is that i created two projects. In one project i have resource file but in another project i don't have.So the project which have resource file is working fine.That pipeline component is created properly and working fine but another one is not working.

Comment: Yes, that is a very common thing to forget about, I have.  The path to the resource file has to match the executing Assembly.  If you named the other different, then moved the files, and did not update the Resources path, it will fail for sure.  Most of the time, you can just copy from the working one, keeping only the Resource file name itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today.  I copied an existing Pipeline from another PipelineComponents C# library.  For whatever reason, the "Build Action" was set to none, instead of "Compile".  So even though the project built and created a .DLL, it wasn't including the C# code that I had modified.

Then I also had to close and re-open Visual Studio, because the previous .DLL as still cached.